# Data Annotations Validation + jQuery.Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This question was asked but was not answered.

I have contact form and I am using Data Annotations for the ContactFormModel.
I add this line `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` to top of the form.

When I click the submit button client validation works perfectly. Now I have changed my mind and want to post the form with jQuery.Ajax.

This time I want to accomplish this.

- Click submit button.
- MicrosoftMVCValidation does the client validation and renders the errors on the clientside.
- If Model is valid I meant if the validation passed I want my jQuery AJAX to get involved.
- But when I clicked the submit button both AJAX post and mvc client validation works. How can I get the things in right order.

1. Mvc Client validation
2. Then jQuery.Ajax Post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Use these JS :

```
jquery-1.4.2.min.js
jquery.validate.js    
MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js    
MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js
```